# How can I make an ICS client available to other computers on the host's network?

Tags: connection-sharing

How can I ping an ICS client from the other computer on the ICS host network? Please see this [image: Diagram of my network].

I would like 'Computer B' to be able to PING the ICS client. Assuming firewalls have been configured properly, how can I address the ICS client from other computers on my network?

|  | ICS HOST | ICS CLIENT | COMPUTER B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CURRENTLY ICS HOST CAN PING | y | y | y |
| CURRENTLY ICS CLIENT CAN PING | y | y | y |
| CURRENTLY COMPUTER B CAN PING | y | **no** | y |

Answer (score 2):

ICS is *very* picky. It doesn't support port forwarding aka destination/reverse NAT either, so connecting into the Ethernet network isn't possible.

You should consider using simple routing - activate routing in your current "ICS Host" (disable ICS) and add a static route to the Ethernet network on the Internet router.